# .htaccess redirect works, but not rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

here is my .htaccess file, it works because the first rewriterule correctly redirects .html -> .php, but I am hoping to remove the .php extension also. if anyone could help me correct my code here I'd appreciate it.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ http://vbwtest.comeze.com/$1.php [R,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
```

Comment: try this `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php [L]` but im not sure

Comment: if you want to remove file extension from the url, you can use MultiViews instead, however be careful if there are files with the same name as a folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.This will rewrite all your requests.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [nc]
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the R flag from your rewrite rule:

```
 RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ http://vbwtest.comeze.com/$1.php [NC]
```

The R in [R,NC] tells it to redirect instead of just rewriting.

Comment: this works, but my code still doesn't remove the extension, or allow people to go to http://vbwtest.comeze.com/about